# Finding the probability of an element given the fact that $P([0, \frac{8}{4+n}]) = \frac{2+e^{-n}}{6}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How can I go about finding the probability of the element $\{0\}$ (i.e., $P(\{0\})$ ) being that given $P([0, \frac{8}{4+n}]) = \frac{2+e^{-n}}{6}$ for all $n \in 1,2, 3, ....$ using the continuity of probabilities?

I am a bit stumped here and not quite sure how to continue. I thought of defining the sequence $\{A_n\}$ by $\{0 \leq x \leq \frac{8}{4+n}\}$, which can be seen as a decreasing sequence, but how can I apply the continuity of probabilities to derive $P(\{0\})$?

Comment: Hint: $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \{0\}$

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now.